# Simple reduction of commitments to one way functions

Tags: one-way-function, commitments

I am looking for an explicit and simple reduction of commitments to one way functions.
I don't care about the number of rounds, only simplicity.
I am aware of the simple reductions you can find in Wikipedia of commitments to one way permutations and to pseudo-random generators, but the first isn't to one way functions so it is not relevant, and for the second to get a reduction to OWFs we will need to go through the reduction of PRGs to OWFs which is not simple. (I didn't actually check that it isn't simple but this is the impression I got from other sources)
Note that the reduction of commitments to PRGs results commitments with only two rounds of interaction, but I wouldn't mind if the resulting commitment scheme has even a polynomial number of rounds - I just want it to be simple.